# System.assertEquals for records in a list? Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, list, insert, for

I have a batch class that inserts Journal records after updating Account records... I am new to apex and cannot think how to test the inserted records in the test class. I have a list to get the journal records, can I do system.asserts inside a for loop? Feel like this is something I've not seen before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do asserts in a for loop, if it makes sense. While it is *rare* to see examples of this on the Internet, there's nothing wrong with it.

For example, let's say I was testing a trigger that looked like this:

```
trigger setTimestamp on Account(before insert) {
  for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
    record.TimeStamp__c = System.now();
  }
}
```

With a unit test like this:

```
@isTest static void testSetTimestamp() {
  Account[] accounts = new Account[0];
  while(accounts.size() < 100) {
    accounts.add(new Account(Name='Test '+accounts.size()));
  }
  Test.startTest();
  insert accounts;
  Test.stopTest();
  accounts = [SELECT TimeStamp__c FROM Account];
  for(Account record: accounts) {
    System.assert(record.TimeStamp__c != null);
  }
}
```

Here, we make sure that all the time stamps are populated. While this is a contrived example, it is conceivable that you'd have a real-life pattern that would follow this same design.

Typically, you'd use System.assert/assertEquals/assertNotEquals in a loop where you're interested in confirming bulkified behavior.